# using anyMatch and lambdas to validate a collection in java

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

I have a method called `isValidDataStreams` where I am checking if any of the members in my collection of `DataStream` violate a check which I have in `isNotEmpty`.

```
public class MyClass {
    private Collection<DataStream> DataStreams;

    /* checking ManifestTemplate/DataStreams */
    public boolean isValidDataStreams()
    {
        if ( getDataStreams().isEmpty() )
            return false;

        for( DataStream dataStream : DataStreams )
        {
            if ( DataStream == null || 
                 !isNotEmpty(DataStream.getAlias() ) || 
                 !isNotEmpty(DataStream.getFilePath() ) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class DataStream {
    private String alias;
    private String filePath;
}
```

I have a feeling this code looks slightly ugly. Is it possible to use lambdas and make this code look better, something along the lines of

```
List<String> test = Arrays.asList("a", "b", null, "c", "d");

        if (test == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (test.stream().anyMatch( x -> { System.out.println( x ); return x == null; } ) ) 
        {
            System.out.println( "dsaflasdk" );
        }
```

I tried to replace it as follows.

```
public boolean isValidDataStreamsLambda()
    {
        if ( getDataStreams().isEmpty() )
            return false;

        if(dataStreams.stream().anyMatch( x -> {!isNotNullAndEmpty(x.getAlias() ) || 
            !isNotNullAndEmpty(x.getFilePath())} ))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But it gives me the following error

> No exception of type boolean can be thrown; an exception type must be
>   a subclass of Throwable

Comment: “But it gives me the following error” Are you sure?  That code has no `throw` statements, so I doubt the code you have shown us could have produced that error.

Comment: Also, changing code that works for something prettier with not time/space benefits, does not strike me as useful

Comment: Here's an idea: don't put a `DataStream` into your `DataStreams` collection if it won't pass the conditionals that you are using while iterating over it. Then you won't need to apply any logic on the way out.

Comment: The main problem is that even you original code doesn’t compile. If it did, we had to conclude that it was impossible to get that compiler error with the new code. However, since the old code obviously isn’t the real code, we can only conclude that help is impossible.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `return DataStreams.stream().allMatch()`?

Answer (score 0):

Method to check if all your DataStream objets stored in a List have theirs values "alias" and "filePath" correctly set :

```
  public static boolean isValidDataStreamsLambda(List<DataStream> dataStreamList) {
     return dataStreamList.stream()
        .filter(d-> d != null && d.getAlias() != null && d.getFilePath() != null && !d.getAlias().isEmpty() && !d.getFilePath().isEmpty())
        .count() == dataStreamList.size();
  }
```